# Is there an easy way to add a copy button to the IndexListing of a non-page model in wagtail?

Tags: wagtail

I have a Snippet model that I'm using ModelAdmin to create, edit, and list in Wagtail. I'd like to create a copy function, and I can see that wagtail supports this out of the box for `Page` objects:

[image]

Before I write custom code to do this, I thought I'd ask if there is any way to easily do this within Wagtail. I didn't find any hooks that would even easily allow adding more buttons, and while I did find [modeladmin-list-display-add-buttons](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.7/reference/contrib/modeladmin/indexview.html#modeladmin-list-display-add-buttons), it seems to only allow me to change the placement of the default edit and delete buttons.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to achieve this. However, it will require custom code, and various overrides and additions in different places. Here are some steps that should help you on your way, with some links to some example code in the wagtailmenus extension, which does this exact thing:

Adding the custom view:

1. Create a custom `CopyView` view (subclassing `wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.views.EditView` will probably be your best starting point). For inspiration, you might want to take a look at one I created for wagtailmenus: https://github.com/rkhleics/wagtailmenus/blob/master/wagtailmenus/views.py#L141
2. Integrate the view with your `ModelAdmin` class, by adding a `copy_view()` method that instantiates your custom view. For example: 
   https://github.com/rkhleics/wagtailmenus/blob/master/wagtailmenus/modeladmin.py#L78
3. Override your `ModelAdmin` class's `get_admin_urls_for_registration()` method, to make the view accessible via a URL. For example: https://github.com/rkhleics/wagtailmenus/blob/master/wagtailmenus/modeladmin.py#L82

Getting the button to show in the listing:

1. Create a custom `ButtonHelper` class by subclassing `wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.helpers.ButtonHelper`.
2. Add a `copy_button()` method to it, that can provide all of the necessary details to create the button. For example: https://github.com/rkhleics/wagtailmenus/blob/master/wagtailmenus/modeladmin.py#L38/
3. Override the `get_buttons_for_obj()` method to output the copy button in the listing along with the others, depending on the user's permissions (e.g. https://github.com/rkhleics/wagtailmenus/blob/master/wagtailmenus/modeladmin.py#L49)
4. Finally, get your `ModelAdmin` class to use your custom `ButtonHelper` instead of the default one, by changing the [`button_helper_class`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin/primer.html#modeladmin-button-helper-class) attribute to reference your custom class.

If you'd like to understand more about all of the various classes within `wagtail.contrib.modeladmin`, I'd suggest reading the [modeladmin customisation primer](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin/primer.html#modeladmin-customisation-primer) page from the official Wagtail documentation.

Comment: thank you for such a detailed answer - worked like a charm!